# SQL 'while' to read a table data to a variable

Tags: sql, loops, while-loop

How could I write a `while` loop to populate data from a table to a variable to be used in a seperate query ?
EX: `select ITEM from Table1`

```
ITEM
A0001
B0001
C0003
D0005
E0032
```

If I can get all that results here under column `ITEM` to `@var1` and then use it in a seperate query like:

```
select * 
from Table2 
where @var1 = Item_table2  <-- a random column in table2
```

This query should match `@var1` from `A0001` to `E0032` to the `Item_table2` column in `Table2`.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop.

```
select * from Table2 where Item_table2 in (select ITEM from Table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want cycle/loop, then use this one:

```
DECLARE @var1 varchar(100)

DECLARE ITEM_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT ITEM FROM Table1

OPEN ITEM_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM ITEM_CURSOR INTO @var1

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

/*Your separate query*/
SELECT * FROM Table2 where @var1 = Item_table2

FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_SMS INTO @var1

END
CLOSE ITEM_CURSOR;
DEALLOCATE ITEM_CURSOR;
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is your first table:

```
mysql> select * from item_table1;
+-------+
| item  |
+-------+
| A0001 |
| B0001 |
| C0003 |
| D0005 |
| E0032 |
+-------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Now, we need to create a view based on this table. The view is the equivalent concept you call in your question by `@var1`:

```
mysql> create view item_table2 as (select * from item_table1);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.30 sec)
```

Let's check our view `item_table2` (`@var1` in your own words):

```
mysql> select * from item_table2;
+-------+
| item  |
+-------+
| A0001 |
| B0001 |
| C0003 |
| D0005 |
| E0032 |
+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, you can select any item from `item_table2` that exists in your `item_table1` like this:

```
 select it2.item from item_table2 it2 where it2.item='A0001'
```