# Loop for stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, while-loop

I have a Stored procedure  that writes data to a table.

What i want to do is use a Variable in the stored procedure
and that variable to be assigned item numbers taken from a separate query

For example : `select ITEM_NUMBER from xTable` 
returns

```
 ITEM_NUMBER
------------
    A1
    B2
    C4
    D7
    J9
```

I want a loop to assign The variable each of these from `A1` to `J9` and run the stored procedure each time

this will run the stored procedure multiple times to run for all the items in my results table.

Thanks

Comment: Use CURSOR for looping.

Comment: hello, answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058848/sql-while-to-read-a-table-data-to-a-variable/27059415#27059415

Comment: At a simple level, use a FAST_FORWARD cursor. But wait, a better way overall is to write another stored procedure that works on the whole set.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your best option here is to use a cursor.

The cursor loops through the query and sets a variable from each row of the query's results. You can call the stored procedure in the body of the cursor, passing in the variable you have populated as a parameter to the procedure.

The syntax for a cursor is as follows:

```
DECLARE @item CHAR(2)

DECLARE item_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT ITEM_NUMBER from xTable

OPEN item_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM item_cursor INTO @item

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

--Execute your stored procedure here, supplying @item as the parameter

FETCH NEXT FROM item_cursor INTO @item

END

CLOSE item_cursor

DEALLOCATE item_cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways

```
Select ITEM_NUMBER into #X from xTable

DECLARE @PartVar varchar(10)
WHILE(0 < (Select Count(*) from #X))
  BEGIN
  SET ROWCOUNT 1
  Select @PartVar = ITEM_NUMBER from #X
  -- EXEC PROC @PartVar
  SET ROWCOUNT 0
  DELETE #X where ITEM_NUMBER = @PartVar
  END
```

or

```
DECLARE @PartVar varchar(10)
DECLARE LOC CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR SELECT ITEM_NUMBER from xTable
OPEN LOC
FETCH NEXT FROM LOC into @PartVar

WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
  EXEC PROC @PartVar
  FETCH NEXT FROM LOC into @PartVar
END

CLOSE LOC
DEALLOCATE LOC
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

FORWARD_ONLY
Specifies that the cursor can only be scrolled from the first to the last row. FETCH NEXT is the only supported fetch option. If FORWARD_ONLY is specified without the STATIC, KEYSET, or DYNAMIC keywords, the cursor operates as a DYNAMIC cursor. When neither FORWARD_ONLY nor SCROLL is specified, FORWARD_ONLY is the default, unless the keywords STATIC, KEYSET, or DYNAMIC are specified. STATIC, KEYSET, and DYNAMIC cursors default to SCROLL. Unlike database APIs such as ODBC and ADO, FORWARD_ONLY is supported with STATIC, KEYSET, and DYNAMIC Transact-SQL cursors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using **CURSOR**.

```
DECLARE @sItemNumber AS VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE TestCursor CURSOR  FOR
(
    select ITEM_NUMBER from xTable
)

OPEN TestCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TestCursor INTO @sItemNumber

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
     EXEC ProcedureName @sItemNumber
     FETCH NEXT FROM TestCursor INTO @sItemNumber
END

CLOSE TestCursor
DEALLOCATE TestCursor
```

Comment: You missed "FETCH NEXT FROM TestCursor INTO @sItemNumber" before the ned of the loop :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this using

```html
DECLARE @itemNumber VARCHAR(50);

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT ITEM_NUMBER FROM xTable;

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @itemNumber


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
       
    -- call your stored procedure here

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @itemNumber  
END  

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```